# Sending Sms by intent but when press back button its not resuming my application

Tags: android, android-intent, back-button

here is my sms() function. when calling intent its work properly but when i press back button then its directly put me on home screen and not resuming my application

```
public class SmsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText number;
    Button smsBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
        number=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
        smsBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sms);

        smsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sms(number.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }
    void sms(String contact_number) {
        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            String number = "sms:" + contact_number;
            i.setData(Uri.parse(number));
            startActivity(i);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getParent(), "SMS cannot be sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

please help me.. Thank you.

Comment: This is pretty much normal. Don't expect system to always keep your Activity in the background, depending on the memory state of the device it can kill your Activity.

Comment: so what can i do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag for that by which you can determine that you need to call super.onbackpress();
or send sms.

I think you are doing both action together

Answer (score 0):

Check your Manifest First,may be for SMSActivity you might have used

android:noHistory="true"

whatever code you have posted it should resume your activity when back pressed